# json request enum

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, enums

We have RestWS where need to pass request in JSON format. This request contains different type of values such as `String`, `List`, `enum` etc.

We figured out how need to pass `String` and `List` (see below) but not sure how to pass `enum` in JSON request object.

Sample JSON Request for `List` and `String` in request:

```
{"firstparam":["195","196"],"secondparam":"test"}
```

First param is `List` and second param is `String`. Similarly we need to know how we can pass `enum` (also in the above request).

Sample `enum` class:

```
@XmlType(name = "Type")
@XmlEnum
public enum Type {

@XmlEnumValue("New")
NEW("New"),
@XmlEnumValue("Delete")
DELETE("Delete"),
@XmlEnumValue("Process")
PROCESS("Process");
private final String value;

WorkingStatusType(String v) {
    value = v;
}

public String value() {
    return value;
}

public static WorkingStatusType fromValue(String v) {
    for (WorkingStatusType c: WorkingStatusType.values()) {
        if (c.value.equals(v)) {
            return c;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(v);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This [Google JSON style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jsoncstyleguide.xml#Enum_Values) might help you.